# SQL Insert - Only insert on this condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert

I have `Table 1`:

```
ID    UserString   Date     
-------------------------
 1    KRBS         4/25/2014    
 2    WEFG         4/24/2014
```

And `Table 2`:

```
ID  UserString + Other user info 
----------------------------------
 1  KRBS    +  . . .. .
```

I'm preforming insert into Table 1 but I would like to make a condition to only insert if the user is already available in Table 2 (only only insert row in table 1 if user already exist in table2)

I'm currently doing two separate SQL checks (one if user exist then insert) but I'm sure there is a better way

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? It isn't obvious from your tags...

Comment: you can try an `insert into t1 (userstring, date) select 'newuserstring', 'newdate' from othertable where ...`

Comment: Sorry SQL Server I removed Mysql

Comment: @MarcB wouldn't it raises an error if there was not nullable fields in Table1 and no results found in Table2?

Comment: @andre: it'd be a 1:1 thing. 5 rows of data found in table2, 5 rows inserted into table1. 0 rows found in table2, 0 rows inserted into table1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to achieve this is to define a `FOREIGN KEY` on the table. This is the simplest and most implicit way to do it, some reference on that can be found on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). That means you will not ever be able to a) insert an entry to this table if no corresponding FK exists, and b) delete from the base table if entries with foreign key are here (in your case, delete the user if it already has the settings ). It will look like:

```
ALTER TABLE NameOfTheTable
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SomeNameForTheKey FOREIGN KEY (nameOfColFromThisTable)
    REFERENCES NameOfTheOtherTable (NameOfTheCOlumnYouAreReferencing);
```

Comment: maybe he is trying to prevent an error being unnecessarily show in his screen, or error log. I think that checking is still useful. But the Foreign Key is always a good point. +1 ;).

Comment: Appreciate everyone's help. I find this to be the best solution Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

try this on mysql:

```
if {{ userId }} in (select UserString from Table2 where UserString = {{ userId }}) then
    insert into Table1 (ID, UserString, Date) values ({{ id }}, {{ userId }}, '{{ date }}')
end if
```

or this on sql server

```
if {{ userId }} in (select UserString from Table2 where UserString = {{ userId }})
    insert into Table1 (ID, UserString, Date) values ({{ id }}, {{ userId }}, '{{ date }}')
```

change {{ var }} to your actual values

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `insert ... select ...` to achieve this, assuming your `ID` column is auto increment:

```
insert into
    table1 (
        UserString,
        Date
    )
select
    table2.UserString,
    @yourDateVariableHere
from
    table2
where
    table2.UserString = @yourUserStringVariableHere
```